# Delphi 10.4.2 cannot install MacOS SDK

Tags: macos, delphi, sdk, delphi-10.4.2

I am using Delphi 10.4.2 Pro. For some odd reason, I cannot see the SDK option for MacOS! Shown in the picture. Could someone help with it? The Mac System are both 10.15.7 Catalina and BigSur. The PA is the latest version 12.2.10.3. Obviously, this something wrong with Delphi side.

[image]

Comment: i wonder if its a limitation since you are on windows.

Comment: Are you able to create an app and change the platform to macOS? If not, you need to install macOS support by going to Tools|Manage Platforms, selecting macOS and installing it

Comment: Try going Delphi menu / Tools / Manage Platforms and then make sure "Delphi macOS" is checked.

Comment: @DanielA.White It is supposed to work on Windows. It seems that macOS platform is not installed. See Dave Nottage's comment.

Answer (score 1):

As  Dave Nottage &  fpiette pointed out above. My installed package data file is damaged when I Delphi menu / Tools / Manage Platforms .
Have to reinstall Delphi. Problem solved. I also noticed MacOS platform is auto selected when install Delphi. Have to manually check it.
thanks guys.